# How to get the Sum of a Group of Records?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-postgresql

I am relatively new to rails and also sql. I am using postgres on production.

I have a `Like` model and through polymorphism, it has attributes `likeable_type` and `likeable_id`, this is how items in my `Photo` model are "liked" by the user. I can access a photo through through a like object too as `like.likeable` when the likeable object has `Photo` as the `likeable_type` and the photo's id as `likeable_id`.

**My Question: I want to be able to get a list of Photos that were liked the most in the past 24 hours, with the most liked one on top and the least liked one at the bottom in the order. How do I do this?**

So far I know my code should look something like

```
likes = Like.find(:all, :conditions => { :created_at => 1.days.ago.utc...Time.now.utc, :likeable_type => "Photo" })
likes = likes.group( --- something here --- , SUM( --- something here --- ))
```

but I am not quite able to figure what the correct syntax shoule be.

any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: In other words, what I am looking to do is count how many of each likeable_id has been created in the like table, in the last 24 hours. Can anyone help?

Comment: Any hint will also be helpful. Really need to figure this one out, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the following:

```
class Photo < AR::Base
  has_many :likes, :as => :likeable
end


class Like < AR::Base
  belongs_to :likeable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Try:

```
@photos = Photo.select("photos.*, count(likes.id) AS likes_count").joins(:likes).where('likes.created_at > ?', 1.day.ago).group('photos.id').order('likes_count DESC')
```

This also allows you to access the number of likes each photo has:

```
@photo.first[:likes_count] # => 4
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like `Like.where(created_at: (1.days.ago.utc...Time.now), linkable_type: 'Photo').first.likes.sum(:something)`, if i right understand your models?

Comment: i think the `.first.likes` does not fit well

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility:

```
Like.where('created_at >= ?',Time.now - 1.day).where('likeable_type = ?','Photo').group('likeable_id').order('count_all DESC').count
```

This will produce sql that looks like (mysql):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)    AS count_all, 
       likeable_id AS likeable_id 
FROM   `likes` 
WHERE  ( created_at >= '2011-11-24 20:43:19' ) 
       AND ( likeable_type = 'Photo' ) 
GROUP  BY likeable_id 
ORDER  BY count_all DESC
```

and you'll get a ActiveSupport::OrderedHash that is {photo_id => likes, photo_id_2 => likes} etc.

If that wasn't polymorphic, and Like was a "belongs_to :photo" - you could do a .group(:photo) and actually have rails create an ordered has of {photo_object => likes} - but with a polymorphic association - you can't do a .group(:likeable) to my knowledge - so you'll have to loop through the hash and do a Photo.find(photo_id_from_hash), which might not be all that efficient depending on how many photos that were liked, so you may have to play around with that list of id's - but at the very least, the above will get you the list without much effort.